# How do academic salaries work in Belgium

Tags: salary, belgium

I'm looking at salary scales published by a Belgian institution.

I see figures published for monthly salaries. Is there a reason why annual salaries are not published? Is the annual salary not as straightforward as monthly salary x 12 months?

Elsewhere, I see mention that '[In addition to their monthly salary, all staff are entitled to holiday pay and an end-of-year bonus](https://www.eui.eu/ProgrammesAndFellowships/AcademicCareersObservatory/AcademicCareersbyCountry/BelgiumFlanders#GrossSalaries)' - how does this work?

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: I'm not in Belgium, but e.g. in my country with the December's salary, if you have a permanent position, you get a bonus which is equivalent to about one month of salary. I imagine that something similar happens in Belgium, even though the amount can be different. For what concerns the holiday pay, it can mean that you're paid also during your summer/yearly holidays, which is fairly standard in Europe.

Comment: As for the question "Is there a reason why annual salaries are not published?": In some countries, people think in terms of monthly salaries instead of annual salaries. In the US, we tend to think of our salary as $/year and that's what we compare. In Germany, people tend to think in $/month and that's what they compare.

Comment: As said above, in Europe is common to think in income/month. Months can be up to 14, like having up to two (eventually partial) months. Holiday pay means that your pay is insensitive to the days out that you have right to. Sometimes they can be converted sometimes not. In all my academical experiences in three different countries there wasn't a strict count though for obvious reason one cannot decide to leave for holidays when summer holidays end, and so on.

Comment: Many thanks Massimo, Wolfgang and Alchimista for responding to and answering my questions. You've covered everything I needed to know. Very much appreciated.